# 3 data sets results help required

Tags: excel-formula, formulas

I need a formula that requires the following to happen:

- if Cell A1 is between 0-150%, return a number 1;
- if between 151-199%, return 2;
- if >200%, return 3.

How can I do this in Excel?

I can get it to produce this `=IF(OR(A1<=150),1,)*IF(OR(A1<151),2)`, but that only produces 2 outcomes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The else part can be a separate `IF`, so:

```
=IF(A1<=150,1,IF(A1<200,2,3))
```